# Python packaging: checking for external programs the right way?

Tags: python, subprocess, packaging

I'm working on an open source Python 3 package I want to distribute on PyPI.  My code needs to call a few different external, third party programs through subprocess calls.  I can't bundle the binary executables, because I'm supporting multiple platforms, and there would be licensing issues.  I can't dynamically link to the executables because some of them don't ship libraries.  In other cases, there's little benefit to writing code to bind to an API to do what a library's command line program can do perfectly, and subprocess invocation has its advantages (e.g. timeout, process isolation).

Surprisingly, the Python documentation from PyPA has almost nothing to say about external programs, even though this is a common operation.

When should my `setup.py` be testing for the presence of these external programs to ensure that the tests run on the target system, not the build system?  What parameters to setup.py should trigger the tests?

I want to warn the user at setup time if their system won't be able to run the package. I expect my program will be run from command line and `import package` will be a rare use case.